# Getting ESRI Feature Service using GDALOpenEx

Tags: gdal

I have used GDAL to import ESRI Shapefile and GML files.  Now I try to use the same API to retrieve ESRI Feature Service.  If I tried to get the data schema and data from https://services6.arcgis.com/Imn3nAubweATciML/arcgis/rest/services/Water_Valves/FeatureServer.

My codes as the following,

```
char** papszOptions = nullptr;
      papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue(papszOptions, "FEATURE_SERVER_PAGING", "YES");
char outfile[1024];
strcpy(outfilename, "https://services6.arcgis.com/Imn3nAubweATciML/arcgis/rest/services/Water_Valves/FeatureServer");
"
GDALDataset* poDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpenEx(outfilename, GDAL_OF_READONLY | GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, papszOptions, NULL);
```

The poDS always return null, and I used the `CPLGetLastErrorMsg()` to retrieve the error message and it also returns `NULL`.  What do I do wrong?

Comment: [Working URL](https://services6.arcgis.com/Imn3nAubweATciML/ArcGIS/rest/services/Water_Valves/FeatureServer/0/query?where=fid+%3D+fid&outfields=*&f=json)

Comment: @user2856 I tried the URL, but it returns "Failed to read TopoJSON data".  Does it mean that I have to pass a query to the GDALOpenEx, and it will open the result as a dataset.  Thank you

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you, but I'm only trying via commandline utility `ogrinfo` not via the C/C++ APIs or python bindings.  Perhaps try prefixing url with `ESRIJSON:` per the [docs](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/esrijson.html). I was just following the syntax shown in the docs of adding a query.